NA reading for one of my groups in Levene's test
Would anyone know why I am getting an NA reading for one of my three groups in Levene's test? I have ten in each group and all three are normally distributed. My dataset is "Rep" and my y variable is "Average".
Advice for a rookie please.
leveneTest(Rep$Average~Rep$Group,centre=mean)
I looked through my descriptive statistics and couldn't see anything obvious. The only thing I could see was that the NA group data had two 0.0 observations.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
